# Help with Font or Span tags in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am using the source editor for the Quote of the Day in SharePoint: **`<span style="text-decoration:underline;">`F`</span>`** This provides me with a daily quote from BrainyQuote.com. However, I want to underline "Quote of the Day" by using Font or Span tags around the bolded text above. How do I do that? Basically, Sharepoint has a layout for Quote of the Day that I like. Brainyquote's feed is sending the words "Quote of the Day" as well. So, I either need to figure out how to delete the words, "Quote of the Day" from Brainyquote or figure out how to format what they are sending so it matches what SharePoint has. Otherwise I have two exact titles or one title that doesn't match the rest of my SharePoint site.

Comment: please post the exact HTML you receive

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.brainyquote.com/link/quotebr.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will get you pretty close to where you want to be:.  Just replace the script tag with this code and you'll be good to go.

Essentially, you're placing the script tag inside of a div and then we apply styles to elements inside of the div.  This gives us a lot of flexibility when needing to manipulate the HTML.

```
<div id="divBrainyQuote">
<style type="text/css">
#divBrainyQuote {
    margin-top:-20px;
}
#divBrainyQuote b {
    display:none;   
    /* text-decoration:underline; This will underline the words "Quote of the Day" */
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.brainyquote.com/link/quotebr.js"></script>
</div>
```